# Spring: Hang after FrameworkServlet.processRequest Successfully completed request

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a problem I am unable to diagnose.

I have

- Tomcat web server Spring
- WebFlow Webapp
- Client on same box as
  tomcat (hence no network issues)

**Every request to the server has the following behaviour:**

Request is received and processed correctly and rapidly. The last line on the log (set to debug) is

> [DEBUG] 2016-08-17 21:44:59,541: org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:999) Successfully completed request

Then a 25 second hang 
Then the response appears in the browser (in correct format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the answer as soon as I posted the question. The problem was a link to a css style sheet on the html response page was broken.

Since the css style sheet was only used on rare occasion, its absence was not noticed by the human eye, but it was noticed by the client which tried to download it for 25 seconds before gracefully and silently giving up